# Why mongodb java driver uses random bytes instead of machine id in ObjectId?

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

Many people say that ObjectId consist of:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch (which will not run out of seconds until the year 2106)
- a 3-byte machine identifier (usually derived from the MAC address),
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

And if the objectId contains all these elements then it's guaranteed that all ids are unique across the cluster. But the docs say that there're no machine and process ids and the objectId contains just a random value (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId)

I looked in the java mongo driver ObjectId generation and found the evidence:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
RANDOM_VALUE1 = secureRandom.nextInt(0x01000000);
RANDOM_VALUE2 = (short) secureRandom.nextInt(0x00008000);

// ...

private ObjectId(final int timestamp, final int counter, final boolean checkCounter) {
    this(timestamp, RANDOM_VALUE1, RANDOM_VALUE2, counter, checkCounter);
}
```

So, it's possible (ok, the probability is really low, but still) that two machines generate the same random numbers and all the consequently generated ids will have clashes very probably. Why such decision has been made? Is it still perfectly unique, but I don't understand something? 
Thanks!

**Edit:** Well, the purpose of the question is: should I implement the retrieving of MAC address and processId and generate ObjectId by myself or leave random 5 bytes number, because there's no difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of this question but just for arguments sake you can argue that the original version also does not guarantee 100% uniqueness. With that said both solution give a unique ("enough"?) id.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert why the original version doesn't guarantee this? Counter (last 3 bytes) guarantees that all ids generated on 1 machine will be unique. And address+process 5 bytes guarantee that objectIds generated on 2 machines **always** will be different, because 2 machines always have different mac addresses (or process id if they run on a single machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why mongodb java driver uses random bytes instead of machine id in ObjectId?

This behavior is [mandated by the ObjectId specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst#random-value).

The same document provides [the rationale](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst#design-rationale):

> Random Value: Originally, this field consisted of the Machine ID and Process ID fields. There were numerous divergences between drivers due to implementation choices, and the Machine ID field traditionally used the MD5 hashing algorithm which can't be used on FIPS compliant machines. In order to allow for a similar behaviour among all drivers and the MongoDB Server, these two fields have been collated together into a single 5-byte random value, unique to a machine and process.

You should not need to implement ObjectId generation, as all MongoDB drivers necessarily need to provide this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the link! So, if I run the code on a normal machine, I should implement the older option of using MAC address for ObjectId generation to achieve 100% uniqueness?

Comment: Could you please explain why? If two machines have different addresses, then generated ObjectIds are 100% different. Are there some cases when mac addresses and process ids are the same?

Comment: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.troubleshooting.doc/GUID-8D7D0126-8E8A-470F-A61E-4197EE32D08F.html